# Android: Accessing internal storage without a context

Tags: android

I'm sure this is a noob question, but I am trying to achieve the following:

On my MainActivity, I have a function called **updateIPList()** which is responsible for reading a file.

This all works. But, now, I want to move that function outside of my activity. I need to be able to read/write to this file from within my **AsyncTask DetermineIP::onPostExecute**.

I will be instantiating **DetermineIP** from **MainActivity** and my **BroadcastReceiver**s or a static class which may not have a context.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Activity context to find the directory or file you want to write to, then just pass that File reference to the other class that needs to write it (no need for a Context to read and write files once you know where they live).